# Error while running bundle install in ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

When I run bundle install, I am getting the below error. It says check the mkmf.log file. How do I locate the mkmf.log file?

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/.rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150228-3404-1f8s19v.rb extconf.rb 
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/.rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby
extconf.rb:45:in `open': No such file or directory @ dir_initialize - /usr/bin/include (Errno::ENOENT)
    from extconf.rb:45:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/.gem/ruby/2.1.3/gems/rjb-1.4.9 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/.gem/ruby/2.1.3/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0-static/rjb-1.4.9/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing rjb (1.4.9), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rjb -v '1.4.9'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I am getting error while trying to install

```
gem install rjb -v '1.4.9'
```

So I found the mkmf.log file. It has the below error. It is looking for jni.h library which is missing. What should I do to resolve this?

```
have_header: checking for jni.h... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest -I/home/.rubies/ruby-2.1.3/include/ruby-2.1.0/x86_64-linux -I/home/.rubies/ruby-2.1.3/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/backward -I/home/.rubies/ruby-2.1.3/include/ruby-2.1.0 -I. -I"/usr/bin/include"     -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -I"/usr/bin/include" conftest.c  -L. -L/home/.rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib -Wl,-R/home/.rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib -L. -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/.rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib -L/home/.rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib -lruby-static  -lpthread -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2:
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */

"gcc -E -I/home/.rubies/ruby-2.1.3/include/ruby-2.1.0/x86_64-linux -I/home/.rubies/ruby-2.1.3/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/backward -I/home/.rubies/ruby-2.1.3/include/ruby-2.1.0 -I. -I"/usr/bin/include"     -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -I"/usr/bin/include"  conftest.c -o conftest.i"
conftest.c:3:17: fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory
 #include <jni.h>
                 ^
compilation terminated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2:
3: #include <jni.h>
/* end */

--------------------

~                                                                                                                                                     
~                                                                                                                                                     
~                                                                                                                                                     
"mkmf.log" 27L, 1710C
```

Comment: Please execute `locate jni.h` from the command line and post your output here.

Comment: @mudasobwa locate jni.h
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include/jni.h

Comment: `export CXXFLAGS='-I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include'` before `gem` execution should help.

Comment: It does not work. I am still getting the same error. checking for jni.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Comment: I am getting the same error. It is still not able to find jni.h . It is failing at the line where #include <jni.h> is written in the c program

Comment: The last suggestion would be to `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64` before `gem`.

Comment: @mudasobwa Coincidently I also tried this :) Yeah this worked. You can post this as anwer. I will mark it then. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

4 posibilities to check for:

- current directory
- ./log
- /home/.gem/ruby/2.1.3/gems/rjb-1.4.9
- /home/.gem/ruby/2.1.3/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0-static/rjb-1.4.9/

If it's not in either of those then try the following command to search your entire system:

`find / -name mkmf.log 2>/dev/null`

To fix the other issue do this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
```

Comment: Thanks. I found the log file and have added more details in my question after editing it. It is failing at the #include <jni.h> line. :(

Comment: It seems like you need to have the java SDK installed and the JAVA_HOME environment variable properly set.

Comment: I have the java sdk installed. Earlier the JAVA_HOME was not set. So I explicitly exported it to the java install path. echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/bin

Comment: "/usr/bin" doesn't sound like a correct value for that, it needs to be more specific. Maybe try "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64" based on your other comment.

Comment: It's not the binary what it needs to find, that's already covered by the PATH environment variable. Could you just try if it works? It won't hurt anything if it doesn't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71931/discussion-between-matugm-and-zack).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it does not work with OpenJdk, sometimes it needs a proprietary full JDK version. I resolved it with this:

[JDK 8](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html)